Suddenly many files have wrong special characters
I have not changed a thing, at least not to my knowledge, but suddenly many of my files, including my config file have such encoding error characters in them. Here is a screenshot from an org-mode buffer:

(Where the first numbers (6,3 and 2) are just (relative?) line numbers.)
When I copy the text out of this buffer and into Firefox; for example into this text field here in this question, the symbols are still there:
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       4652c464-90f7-4ba8-9e58-1496b4660946
:END:
#+title: 2024-07-01
#+filetags: :Arbeit:

I know this has something to do with encoding, but I can not figure out what to do. M-x describe-current-coding-system gives Coding system for saving this buffer: t -- raw-text-unix
I do M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system RET utf-8 gives
These default coding systems were tried to encode the following
problematic characters in the buffer ‘config.el’:

It follows with a list of the problematic characters. I can not copy them out of the buffer and post them here because emacs crashes when I paste them here.
I can not paste in this:
(setq
    org-superstar-headline-bullets-list '("⁖" "◉" "○" "✸" "✿")
)

because it ends up in an emacs buffer as this:

When I then copy that text and paste it into Firefox, it ends up as question marks.
However I can still do M-x insert-char and insert some emoji, for example "see no evil monkey": 
I can then happily paste this around into Firefox and back into emacs.
I use emacs 29.3.50 in Gentoo in WSL.

Do you see the same problem with emacs -Q (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

I don't understand what you are showing: what are the 6, 3 and 2 at the beginning of each line in the first display?  What do you mean by when I copy the text out of this? Out of what? Is the first display a screenshot of an Emacs buffer? If so, what is the coding system of the buffer? To find out, do M-x describe-current-coding-system and tell us what the first line of the *Help* buffer says. How exactly do you get the second display, step-by-excruciating-step? Please edit the question and add ALL this information.

@Drew: It happens with emcas -Q as well.

When you ask a question, simplify the situation as much as possible to concentrate on the problem at hand. Here e.g. , the line numbers are irrelevant, so please turn them off in screenshots (unless your question is about those line numbers). Describe what you did exactly, so we can try to reproduce the problem. If the description is vague, we are left guessing (or worse: dazed and confused).

Ok, I figured it out partially.
I ran M-x set-buffer-file-encoding-system utf-8 to make sure the file is encoded in utf-8.
There must have been an update to wsl in the last few days, because I figured it is only transforming (some) special characters to question marks, when I copy this text from a Windows program into WSL emacs. If I run Firefox in WSL for example, copying works just as it should.
I still do not know what caused my config and other files to change the encoded characters in the first place. Most of those files are saved inside WSL, so I don't think Windows would touch them.

I still don't understand what happened (not even with the additional explanations - but thanks for adding them): undoubtedly, that raw-text-unix had something to do with it.

Your expression (setq ....) is bad formatted - the bullet code is a
string composed from the question mark followed by the symbol's code. See
the bullet definition in file org-superstar.el. That is Emacs display
mechanics, failing to follow it may result in display freezing. Also it is
not clear why the need to re-define the bullets, since they are alredy defined/configured.
